# What's wrong with the following Unix shell script?

Tags: shell, unix

I have entered this shell script and its showing errors when compiling

```
echo Enter basic Salary
read bs
if [ $bs -lt 1500 ]
then
 hra= echo ´$bs \* 10 / 100´|bc
fi
gs= echo ´$bs + $hra´|bc
echo $gs
```

The errors are:

```
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: \302
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: \264
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: \302
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: \264
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: \302
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: \264
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: \302
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: \264
(standard_in) 2: syntax error
```

Comment: Nonfloating arithmetic is best done this way: `hra=$((bs * 10 / 100))` (called *Arithmetic Expansion*). No need for an extra process.

Answer (score 1):

One problem is (or, rather, 4 problems are) the use of `´` in place of `'` or `"`.

There is another character in there also causing trouble, unless the acute accent is encoded in UTF-8 or UTF-16<sup>†</sup>

Another problem is the use of spaces around assignments; these do not fly in the shell.  You must not have spaces on either side of the assignment.

```
echo Enter basic Salary
read bs
if [ "$bs" -lt 1500 ]
then hra=$(echo "$bs * 10 / 100"|bc)
fi
gs=$(echo "$bs + $hra"|bc)
echo $gs
```

You don't really need the variable `gs`; you could write:

```
echo "$bs + $hra" | bc
```

Note that if `bs` is not less than 1500, you get a ill-defined value for `hra` (whatever happens to be left over, or blank if it is unset).

<sup>†</sup> It looks like you have UTF-8 encoded data.

```
$ echo "´" | odx
0x0000: C2 B4 0A                                          ...
0x0003:
$ echo "´" | utf8-unicode
0xC2 0xB4 = U+00B4
0x0A = U+000A
$ bc | cat
ibase=16
obase=8
C2
302
B4
264
quit
$
```

U+00B4 is ACUTE ACCENT in Unicode.

Comment: +1, and another problem is that variables must be double-quoted: `"$bs"`, except in very few situations.

Comment: @JoSo: yes, see my update which I posted almost synchronously with your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Too many Errors:

1. As stated by Jonathan, is using ´ in place of `.
2. Do not use space while assigning values to variables.
3. Create the data before assigning it to a variable.

For e.g.
hra=`echo $bs \* 10 / 100|bc`

Also, if the input exceeds 1500, then it will give out the error. So you need to do something with it.

For e.g.
echo "Enter basic Salary"
read bs
if [ $bs -lt 1500 ]
then
hra=`echo $bs \* 10 / 100|bc`
else
hra=`echo $bs \* 5 / 100|bc`
fi
gs=`echo $bs + $hra|bc`
echo $gs